# Are there any C-like (in syntax) scripting languages other than JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: scripting, scripting-language

I am looking for a general-purpose (considering PHP is actually made and initially meant (I understand they are be used different ways some times) for server side Web and JavaScript for client-side web) with C/C++/C#/Java-like syntax. Do you know of such?

Comment: You should probably be a bit more precise about what you mean by "Scripting" language. Dynamic typing? Interpreted? Have good system interface (e.g. can be used to write system "glue" scripts)?

Answer (score 2):

[Mythryl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythryl) is a general-purpose scripting languages deliberately designed around C syntax.

Comment: Hmm... Curious. "Mythryl provides Perl-like scripting convenience in a typed, compiled language" (from the link above). I'm not sure if I should be excited at the idea or horrified :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Pike](http://pike.ida.liu.se/) with [Fins](http://hww3.riverweb.com/space/pike/Fins)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/), an embeddable C/C++ interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Just look through the [Comparison of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages), and see which ones fit your needs best. You might look at the language with dynamic [Type Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages#Type_systems), because those are scripting languages. Hyped languages include Scala, Ruby (with the Ruby on Rails web framework), Groovy and others, if you need a start.

Comment: I like Scala the best of all languages I've ever seen, but it seems that script mode is just of an auxiliary purpose there. I don't think I can just start a source file with something like  #!/usr/bin/scala and use it for system scripting.

Comment: Depends on your system. On Ubuntu, as I notices just one week ago, you can even start a C-program directly on the command line. It gets compiled and started on the fly, very impressive. And I am sure you can configure it to start a Scala script like this, too.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Wikipedia's C language entry lists many: "*C has directly or indirectly influenced many later languages such as Java, Perl, Python, PHP, JavaScript, LPC, C# and Unix's C Shell*"

**Specifically, for general-purpose "scripting" language that is very similar to C, I would strongly recommend Perl which fits the bill perfectly.**

Perl's syntax (or at least a sub-set of it) is VERY C-like (to the point that ex-C programmers starting in Perl are unfortunately known to code in "C-ish Perl" style which is pretty much straight up C).

In additional to general syntax ideas, Perl supports a vast majority of C system functions and many other C-isms (e.g. fully functional `printf`, process control and IPC).

Perl these days is definitely a general purpose language - it is used for anything from web development (including modern frameworks like Catalyst MVC, Plack etc...), to enterprise software development including full blown servers, to system administration scripting and general "scripting" glue tasks.

In addition, it supports both Object Oriented programming (either using classic Perl OOP or using modern Moose), as well as functional programming.

Please note that when evaluating Perl, you should not rely on the [numerous myths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755168/perl-myths) that exist out there - most of these are due to either people not being sufficiently familiar with Perl, or judging Perl based on a large mass of poor-code-quality dirty scripts written by system administrators who weren't software developers, or judging Perl based on its features in Perl versions that were popular 15 years ago (e.g. any criticism of Perl OOP circa 1998 is pretty much useless unless the person doing it is closely familiar with Moose).

---

P.S. Since your questions seems to be in  "...coming from PHP" context, you should also note that PHP is in fact very similar to a subset of Perl - by design. To quote from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php):

> The syntax itself was similar to that of Perl, albeit much more limited, simple, and somewhat inconsistent.

Matter of fact, PHP started out as a collection of Perl CGI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a new project called Cpy, using Python's execution engine, but wrting codes in C-syntax. It is built with ANTLR and Python. Take a look at it: http://www.ideawu.com/cpy/

Answer (score 0):

[Pawn](http://www.compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm). Not general purpose (depending on your definition) but very good as a small embedded language.